# Jquery UI Dialog Title shows up as uppercase

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, title, uppercase

I am trying to use a Jquery UI Modal Dialog for  confirmation and the Title appears as upper case even when I set it to be lower case in the settings. My simple code below.

I am using jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom plugin.

```
var professionalID = $(this).attr("professionalID");
var $deleteUserDialog = $('<div></div>')
  .html('The user entry will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?')
  .dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: 'delete user?',
  buttons: {
    "Delete": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      deleteUser(professionalID);
    },
    "Cancel": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
$deleteUserDialog.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fiddle displays the dialog with a lowercase title:
http://jsfiddle.net/3yp8N/

I used your code without modifications.

It's a shot in the dark, but maybe you should check one of your css for the property text-transform

For example:

```
p: {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Will turn the all the content in all p elements to uppercase..

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks! I found it buried deep in one of the .css files. Chrome debugger helped as well. I appreciate your help!